# How to add static library that requires iOS4 to a project with deployment target set to 3.0?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4, static-libraries

I'd like to add static library that requires at least iOS4 to a project that has deployment target set to 3.0 - how do I do that?

My guess is that I add binary and make it weak-linked (setting name "Optional" under target's 'Build Phases' -> 'Link Binary With Libraries' option) and ensure with run-time iOS version check (UIDevice's systemVersion property), that library's code doesn't get called on devices with iOS version lower than 4.0. Correct?

Is there anything I should do more?

Comment: Weak linkage on a static library?

Comment: @Till: yes, a static library - i.e. not a framework, but a *.a file that has header file shipped with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to frameworks (dynamic libraries) that your static library depends on, then you are right, those should be marked optional. 
Additionally, you will have to do a runtime check to prevent failures on invocation of non existent functionality.

Comment: Is .a file(Universal) made in latest version will worked in project deployment target (say 9.3 will work on 8.0 )?